# MEF Composition ImportMany yield two versions of same class

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I haven't been able to find an answer for my problem. I'm using MEF to find and create my classes that implement IPlugIn, but I end up with two versions of each PlugIn class. I have determined that the AggregateCatalog only contains one Assembly that contains only 1 type of each class as a Part, but I am still getting two instances of each as the end result. I'm probably just doing something stupid, but I haven't found it yet. I'd appreciate any help...

```
...

    [ImportMany(typeof(IPlugIn))]
     public System.Lazy>[] Plugins { get; set; }

...
    //aggregatecatalog only contains one dll containing plugin classes, 4 of them
    container = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog,
                                         CompositionOptions.DisableSilentRejection 
                                         | CompositionOptions.IsThreadSafe);\

    container.SatisfyImportsOnce(this);

    ...
    public void StartAll()
    {
    //We have 8 PlugIns here?? How? 
    if (Plugins == null || Plugins.Count() == 0)
    {

       log.Warn("No PlugIns Available to Start!");
       return;
    }

        foreach (var plug in Plugins)
        {
            log.Info("Starting PlugIn: " + plug.Value.GetName());
            plug.Value.Start();
        }
    }

   ...

    [Export(typeof(IPlugIn))]
    public class MyPlugIn : BasePlugIn, IPlugIn

    ...
```

I'm debugging in Visual Studio. I clearly see only one Assembly loading. The CompositionContainer has only 1 of each. After SatisfyImportOnce in StartAll(), I have two instances of each IPlugIn classes. Is this something with the way I am using ImportMany? I am open to any ideas.

Comment: What do your exports look like? I've had this happen to me when my export statements weren't setup correctly.

Comment: I added an example of my Export. You see any problem with it?

Comment: First, your BasePlugIn and IPlugIn don't have an `Export` tag, do they? Next, something you could try is removing the `typeof(IPlugIn)` from your `Export` and `ImportMany`. Don't know why that would help, but I noticed I don't have that on my `Export`s and `ImportMany`s.

Comment: try replacing container.SatisfyImportsOnce(this) with container.ComposeParts(this). I'm not familiar with SatisfyImportsOnce, but I use ComposeParts all the time with importmany.

Comment: I've tried ComposeParts before and still same issue. I should have mentioned that. No BasePlugIn and IPlugIn do not have Export. removing typeof had no effect. I still get two instances of each class... weird stuff...any other ideas?

Comment: What specific catalogs have you added to the AggregateCatalog?

Comment: Just 1 which corresponds to the project I am in.

Comment: What happens if you add `[InheritedExport(typeof(IPlugin))]` to `IPlugin` and remove the other exports?

Comment: That actually caused the plugins not to be recognized at all and I ended up with 0 plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution turned out to be simple. I removed the [InheritedExport] from the IPlugIn interface completely and that created the correct number of plugins. If I removed the [Export... from each PlugIn subclass, I got no plugins at all. It was the combination of the two that created the multiple instances.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an `InheritedExport` attribute on your interface, you must use an `InheritedExport` on your class that implements the interface. Applying `Export` results in an additional part being composed, which is what you found out.

Also, if you want to apply any other `ExportMetadata` to a class that implements an interface with `InheritedExport`, you must add the `InheritedExport` attribute *again* in order to add the metadata (replacing the inherited metadata, even if there is none). This is not addressed in the MSDN documentation for [InheritedExport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.COMPONENTMODEL.COMPOSITION.INHERITEDEXPORTATTRIBUTE%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2CVERSION%3DV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) or [ExportMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.exportmetadataattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but I ran across some vague references in other obscure Microsoft documentation.